# Any libraries available for contact sync from multiple sources

Tags: library, java, synchronization, contact-manager

We are planning to write a CRM application, which mainly deals with Contacts.

We need to fetch contacts from multiple sources like Gmail,Outlook,Shopify,Stripe and others.

So our app needs two way sync of contacts from above mentioned sources.

Is there any open source/paid libraries available to full fill our needs

I will use this library in our application for two-way sync contacts from multiple sources

I did a search I have found couple of products, but we need a library so that we can use it as a API.

We want to write our app in Java

Thanks